# Remove all files in a directory (do not touch any folders or anything within them)

Tags: linux, bash, shell, unix

I would like to know whether `rm` can remove all files within a directory (but not the subfolders or files within the subfolders)?

I know some people use:

```
rm -f /direcname/*.*
```

but this assumes the filename has an extension which not all do (I want all files - with or without an extension to be removed).

Comment: is find the only answer? I am surprised that rm cannot handle this without giving warnings as it seems like such a simple operation

Comment: what's wrong with `find`? I understand that it's a bit clunky seeming, but it's better to keep `rm` simple and `find` clunky than ask for every feature to be added to `rm` (rendering it just as clunky as `find`)

Answer (score 37):

Although find allows you to delete files using `-exec rm {} \;` you can use

```
find /direcname -maxdepth 1 -type f -delete
```

and it is faster. Using -delete implies the -depth option, which means process directory contents before directory.

Comment: using `-delete` as opposed to `-exec` keeps several instances of rm from being launched to delete the files found by executing **find**

Comment: You had the most useful answer all over the interwebz :D cheers! It made my day!

Comment: Use `find . -maxdepth 1 -type f -delete` if you're already in the directory

Comment: fwiw, `-exec rm {} +` is equivalent in speed

Answer (score 8):

```
find /direcname -maxdepth 1 -type f -exec rm {} \;
```

Explanation:

- `find` searches for files and directories within `/direcname`
- `-maxdepth` restricts it to looking for files and directories that are direct children of `/direcname`
- `-type f` restricts the search to files
- `-exec rm {} \;` runs the command `rm {}` for each file (after substituting the file's path in place of `{}`).

Comment: sophisticated way of doing ot

Comment: you can also use `-delete` rather than `-exec rm {} \;`

Comment: @Shep, yep, that is better. Although I noticed troller used that, so I'll leave that to them and won't change my answer.

Answer (score 3):

> I would like to know whether rm can remove all files within a directory (but not the subfolders or files within the subfolders)?

That's easy:

```
$ rm folder/*
```

Without the `-r`, the `rm` command won't touch sub-directories or the files they contain. This will only remove the files in `folder` and not the sub-directories or their files.

You will see *errors* telling you that *folder/foo* is a directory can cannot be removed, but that's actually okay with you. If you want to eliminate these messages, just redirect STDERR:

```
$ rm folder/* 2> /dev/null
```

By the way, the exit status of the `rm` command may not be zero, so you can't check `rm` for errors. If that's important, you'll have to loop:

```
$ for file in *
> do
> [[ -f $file ]] && rm $file
> [[ $? -ne 0 ]] && echo "Error in removing file '$file'"
> done
```

This should work in BASH even if the file names have spaces in them.

Answer (score 2):

You can use

```
find /direcname -maxdepth 1 -type f -exec rm -f {} \;
```

Comment: This -is- was recursive, which the OP did NOT want.

Comment: Sure, I did forgot the maxdepth argument. Fixed.

Answer (score 2):

A shell solution (without the non-standard find -maxdepth) would be

```
for file in .* *; do
   test -f "$file" && rm "$file"
done
```

Comment: what does the space between the 2 asterix mean?

Comment: In some shells or with certain parameter settings, `*` does not glob filenames beginning with a dot, thus I explicitly request all `.profile` etc. with `.*`. The following `*` globs all other files. If the latter also globs dot files, this ends up with duplicate names, which is harmless, as the `test -f` will then skip the already removed file.

Answer (score 1):

Some shells, notably [zsh](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/) and perhaps bash version 4 (but not version 3), have a syntax to do that.

With zsh you might just type

```
rm /dir/path/*(.)
```

and if you would want to remove any file whose name starts with foo, recursively in subdirectories, you could do

```
rm /dir/path/**/foo*(.)
```

the double star feature is (with IMHO better interactive completion) in my opinion enough to switch to zsh for interactive shells. YMMV

The dot in parenthesis suffix indicates that you want only files (not symlinks or directories) to be expanded by the zsh shell.

Answer (score 1):

Unix isn't DOS. There is no special "extension" field in a file name. Any characters after a dot are just part of the name and are called the suffix. There can be more than one suffix, for example`.tar.gz`.  The shell glob character `*` matches across the `.` character; it is oblivious to suffixes. So the MS-DOS `*.*` is just `*` In Unix.

Almost. `*` does not match files which start with a `.`. Objects named with a leading dot are, by convention, "hidden". They do not show up in `ls` either unless you specify `-a`.

(This means that the `.` and `..` directory entries for "self" and "parent" are considered hidden.)

To match hidden entries also, use `.*`

The `rm` command does not remove directories (when not operated recursively with `-r`).
Try `rm <directory>` and see. Even if the directory is empty, it will refuse.

So, the way you remove all (non-hidden) files, pipes, devices, sockets and symbolic links from a directory (but leave the subdirectories alone) is in fact:

```
rm /path/to/directory/*
```

to also remove the hidden ones which start with `.`:

```
rm /path/to/directory/{*,.*}
```

This syntax is brace expansion. Brace expansion is not pattern matching; it is just a short-hand for generating multiple arguments, in this case:

```
rm /path/to/directory/* /path/to/directory/.*
```

this expansion takes place first first and then globbing takes place to generate the names to be deleted.

Note that various solutions posted here have various issues:

```
find /path/to/directory -type f -delete

# -delete is not Unix standard; GNU find extension
# without -maxdepth 1 this will recurse over all files
# -maxdepth is also a GNU extension
# -type f finds only files; so this neglects to delete symlinks, fifos, etc.
```

The GNU find solutions have the benefit that they work even if the number of directory entries to be deleted is huge: too large to pass in a single call to `rm`. Another benefit is that the built-in `-delete` does not have issues with passing funny path names to an external command.

The portable workaround for the problem of too many directory entries is to list the entries with `ls` and pipe to `xargs`:

```
( cd /path/to/directory ; ls -a | xargs rm -- )
```

The parentheses mean "do these commands in a sub-process"; this way the effect of the `cd` is forgotten, which is useful in scripting. `ls -a` includes the hidden files.

We now include a `--` after `rm` which means "this is the last option; everything else is a non-option argument". This guards us against directory entries whose names are indistinguishable from options. What if a file is called `-rf` and ends up the first argument? Then you have  `rm -rf ...` which will blow off subdirectories.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way to do this is to use:

```
rm *
```

In order to remove directories, you must specify the option -r

```
rm -r
```

so your directories and anything contained in them will not be removed by using

```
rm *
```

per the man page for rm, its purpose is to remove files, which is why this works